# Why the product button aren't adding into the cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, addtocart, buy-now

In product detail page, I have two buttons. One is **Buy now** and another one is **Add to Cart**. When I click on **Add to cart** button, products are adding into the cart.

But when I'm clicking on **Buy now** button, the page is redirecting to checkout page but products aren't adding in the cart. Previously this functionality was working. After I switched to SSL configuration, buy button isn't working.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Access this route into the admin panel:

> System > Configuration > Web > Session Cookie Management

Make sure that both **Cookie Path** and C**ookie Domain** are blank then save.